# Is my understanding of DTD correct?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am self-learning XML and here is the first DTD I wrote. Below is the XML data followed by the DTD.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="unicode" ?>
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "validator.dtd">

<people>
    <student>
        <name>John</name>
        <course>Computer Technology</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <student>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>
</people>
```

and the DTD

```
<!ELEMENT people (student)*>
<!ELEMENT student (name,course,semester,scheme)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT course (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT semester (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT scheme (#PCDATA)>
```

Here is my understanding of the DTD so far.
I have a root named `people` that has `student` inside of it. Now, since I have a `*` then I can have `zero or more` of students inside. But I guess it should be changed to `+` (one or more) because it makes more sense ?

Inside `student` is name, course semester and scheme. When I leave out any symbols after the closing parentheses then it means that each of these tags can appear only once inside the student tag. This means a student can not have more than one name, more than one semester, etc

Finally, name, course, semester and scheme have `#PCDATA` which means data is going to be parsed by someone else and **does excluding the symbol here make a difference?**

Comment: "unicode" is not a valid encoding name. Use the name of an actual encoding, such as "UTF-8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> When I leave out any symbols after the closing parentheses then it
>   means that each of these tags can appear only once inside the student
>   tag.

I would only add that each of those tags **must** appear once; they are not optional unless you have a `?` or `*`. Also, they must appear in that order (since you used `,`).

`#PCDATA` means parsed character data which is basically text that will be parsed by the parser. For example, the text "`Sample &text;`" would get parsed and the `&text;` entity reference would be resolved.

The only time you really need a symbol (occurrence indicator) for `#PCDATA` is when you have mixed content (both text and elements). It has to be an `*` too:

```
<!ELEMENT elem (#PCDATA|anotherElem)*>
```